# shell_exec phpfile

Tags: php, shellexecute, pcntl

I currently use this code:

```
if(isset($_POST['url']) && isset($_POST['trefwoorden']) )
{
  mysql_connect('localhost', 'crawler', 'whathasbeenseencannotbeunseen');
  mysql_select_db("crawler");
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO jobs (jobID, url, trefwoorden) VALUES ('', '".$_POST['url']."', '".$_POST['trefwoorden']."')");
  $output = shell_exec("./content.php " .mysql_insert_id());
  echo $output;

}
```

In my content.php I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
echo 'HET WERKT';
?>
```

Now I want to see if my shell_exec actually works by filling in the form and submitting it: but it doesn't echo anything at all.

Did I write wrong code?

Comment: Did you install the CLI (command-line interface) to PHP? Does /usr/bin/php exist? Is content.php executable? Did you try to run it from the shell?

Comment: I might tell a mistake but shouldn't it be `$output = shell_exec("./content.php");$output .= mysql_insert_id();` ? 'Cause it doesn't seem to me that `mysql_insert_id()` is a part of the shell cmd... I might be wrong, enlight me! http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. This may help you.

```
shell_exec('usr/local/bin/php -l content.php'. mysql_insert_id())
```

or

```
shell_exec('usr/local/bin/php -content.php'. mysql_insert_id())
```

All the best.

Thanks,

Kanji

Comment: Also not working for me, got some random tests working but my actual code won't start.

Will reply if any of your code work :)!

Answer (score 0):

.. Maybe this will work for you:

```
shell_exec('php -l content.php'. mysql_insert_id())
```

Or;

1. PHP is running in safe_mode
2. Apache does not have the permissions to execute the script

Comment: Doesn't give my echo back, returns: no errors detected in content.php

Answer (score 0):

Why do you invoke a PHP file and not including it?

Besides, I agree with Chouchenos because this line of code:

```
shell_exec('php -l content.php'. mysql_insert_id())
```

will execute like this "php -l content.php132" if mysql_insert_id() returns the id 132.

This might be a problem because `content.php132` might not be existant.

Comment: Because i need to get a process on the background to speed up my process of crawling webpage.

Comment: hmm try this mysql_query("INSERT INTO jobs (jobID, url, trefwoorden,used) VALUES ('', '".$_POST['url']."', '".$_POST['trefwoorden']."',0)"); and add a line in that takes the lowes jobID that is not used to the content.php and lat it work on that job.